# JS Adding a button to a listbox

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm writing a JS app and am trying to create a list box which adds content chosen by the user. It should be something like this:

Content 1 | +
Content 2 | +
...
Content 5 | +

Where the content is an onclick button that when clicked by the user projects a sound and the + is the add button so that you add that content to the list.

This is what I'm working with right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
var cmajor = new Audio();
var cminor = new Audio();
var c_augmented = new Audio();
var c_diminished = new Audio();

cmajor.src = "cmajor.mp3";
cminor.src = "cminor.mp3";
c_augmented.src = new "c_augmented.mp3"
c_diminished.src = new "c_diminished.mp3"

function PlaySound(acorde) {
  switch (acorde) {
    case 'cmajor':
      cmajor.play();
      break;
    case 'cminor':
      cminor.play();
      break;
    case 'c_augmented':
      c_augmented.play();
      break;
    case 'c_diminished':
      c_diminished.play();
      break;
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<audio id="cmajor"> </audio>
<button onclick="PlaySound('cmajor')"> C major </button>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">+</button>

<audio id="cminor"> </audio>
<button onclick="PlaySound('cminor')"> C minor </button>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">+</button>

<audio id="c_augmented"> </audio>
<button onclick="PlaySound('c_augmented')"> C augmented </button>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">+</button>

<audio id="c_diminished"> </audio>
<button onclick="PlaySound('c_diminished')"> C diminished </button>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">+</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsfiddle.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

https://jsfiddle.net/422Lojct/28/

```
    var cmajor = new Audio();
var cminor = new Audio();
var c_augmented = new Audio();
var c_diminished = new Audio();

cmajor.src = "cmajor.mp3";
cminor.src = "cminor.mp3";
c_augmented.src = "c_augmented.mp3";
c_diminished.src = "c_diminished.mp3";

function PlaySound(acorde) {
  switch (acorde) {
    case 'cmajor':
      cmajor.play();
      break;
    case 'cminor':
      cminor.play();
      break;
    case 'c_augmented':
      c_augmented.play();
      break;
    case 'c_diminished':
      c_diminished.play();
      break;
  }
}

function addList(item) {
  console.log(item);
  document.getElementById('listBox').appendChild(item);
}
```

The HTML

```
<body>

  <audio id="cmajor"> </audio>
  <button onclick="PlaySound('cmajor')"> C major </button>
  <button type="button" onclick="addList(cmajor)">+</button>

  <audio id="cminor"> </audio>
  <button onclick="PlaySound('cminor')"> C minor </button>
  <button type="button" onclick="addList(cminor)">+</button>

  <audio id="c_augmented"> </audio>
  <button onclick="PlaySound('c_augmented')"> C augmented </button>
  <button type="button" onclick="addList(c_augmented)">+</button>

  <audio id="c_diminished"> </audio>
  <button onclick="PlaySound('c_diminished')"> C diminished </button>
  <button type="button" onclick="addList(c_diminished)">+</button>

  <div id="listBox">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but the code you wrote isn't working for me.